# Smart Tee wont connect to camera

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I have a C# DirectShow.net program that i created on a windows 7 32bit machine. It works on my development machine and it works on xp 32bit and vista 32bit virtual machines.

What im having an issue with is the deployment of this program. I will take the program as is and put it on a separate machine. and it wont run.

I put the code on a windows 7 64bit machine and got the errors:

```
Application has returned a referral from the server
```

so i stopped registering my DLLs in code for now and just registered them by hand.
after that i restarted my program and get another error

```
StackoverflowException at Graph.connect( pinout, pinin );
```

In the code where i connect the camera to the Smart Tee filter. I have GraphStudio on the machine and try to build the graph in it, but it just keeps crashing whenever i connect filters. The pins are not null, they found the filters and the graph isnt null. not sure what is occuring.

I have also tried on win 7 32bit machines other then my own and get the same issue.
confusing the heck out of me.

I have 2 windows 7 32bit virtual machines. 1 is running through Virtual PC, the other is through Virtual Box. 1 will crash on my program and crash when trying to replicate the graph in graphstudio. Virtual PC wont crash at all. both are using the exact samewin7 version :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that after installing the LifeCam software for my webcam, this started happening. Lifecam software blocked access to their camera from my program. Big thanks to MS for that.

downloading the absolute newest update from microsoft's specific website lets me reuse it again